# WebSharper : How to use the .On event handler

Tags: jquery, f#, websharper

I'm trying to use JQuery provide by WebSharper to catch the following event : selectstart.

So I write the following code :

```
JQuery.Of(".editorArea").On("selectstart", fun x ->
    (
        JavaScript.Log("test")
        true
    )
)
```

The problem is this never print the `test` string in the console. And I don't know how to use x which have the `obj` type so I can't really access the event informations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code unless you're binding the event to a textarea, input:password or input:text. In that case you need to listen to the "select" event instead of "selectstart" like in the example below (notice the event object's explicit downcast to `Dom.Event` in order to access its information):

```
[<InlineAttribute "$elt.value.substring($elt.selectionStart, $elt.selectionEnd)">]
let selectedText elt = X<string>

let textareaSelection() =
    TextArea [Text "Select me"; Attr.Class "editorArea"]
    |>! OnAfterRender (fun _ ->
        JQuery.Of(".editorArea").On("select", fun x ->
            (As<Dom.Event> x).CurrentTarget
            |> selectedText
            |> JavaScript.Log
            true)     
        )
```

Comment: Thans for your reply. I am using a `div editable`and it's works like a charm :). I love WebSharper but I find that it's lack documentation on some point. Or it's just because I beginning with it.